# bit shift on linux 64bit OS

Tags: c++, linux, 64-bit, bit, shift

Here is my code:

```
union myStruct
{
    struct
    {
        uint32_t
            A       : 1,  // 00
            B       : 4,  // 04:01
            C       : 25, // 29:05
            D       : 2;  // 31:30
    } sData;
    uint32_t        ulData;
};
myStruct p;
p.ulData = 0;

p.sData.C = 0x524;

printf("p.ulData = %x\n", p.ulData);
printf("p.sData.C = %x\n", p.sData.C);
printf("p.sData.D = %x\n", p.sData.D);

uint32_t data32 = p.sData.C << 0x15;
printf("data32 = %x \n", data32);

uint64_t data64const32 = static_cast<uint32_t>(p.sData.C) << 0x15;
printf("data64const32 = %lx \n", data64const32);

uint64_t data64const64 = static_cast<uint64_t>(p.sData.C) << 0x15;
printf("data64const64 = %lx \n", data64const64);

uint64_t data64 = p.sData.C << 0x15;
printf("data64 = %lx \n", data64);
```

Output is:

```
#p.ulData = a480    
#p.sData.C = 524
#p.sData.D = 0
#data32 = a4800000
#data64const32 = a4800000
#data64const64 = a4800000
#data64 = ffffffffa4800000
```

Apparently last output is wrong.

More interesting, the output is wrong only on linux

```
Distributor ID: SUSE LINUX
Description:    SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
Release:        11
g++ (GCC) 6.3.0
```

It outputs correctly on windows.(win10/VS2017)

I'm kind of understand the issue is related to bit shift on a 64bit OS. And I know how to fix it.

What I'm worried is there might be more codes like this in my project. It's hard to find them out.

Is there a way to catch such code with any g++ compile options?

Comment: What happens if you use the `PRIx64` formatting macro instead of `%lx`?

Comment: Hi Paul, It is best to start explaining the problem, tell what is expected and what you get, followed by a minimal example to reproduce the problem such as the 6 last lines of code which are the only ones that matter.